# sysfs folder symbolic link behavior

Tags: linux, symlink, sysfs

I encountered this behavior that I can't explain. In the sysfs, there is a symbolic link but it looks impossible to me:

```
me@test:/sys/block/sde$ ll
...
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Oct  1  2019 device -> ../../../8:0:0:0
...

me@test:/sys/block/sde$ cd ../../../8:0:0:0
me@test:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:17.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.3/host8/target8:0:0/8:0:0:0$
```

but obviously three level up gets me to the root folder, so how does this happen?

```
me@test:/sys/block/sde$ cd ../../../
me@test:/$
```

Comment: Take a look at the real path of `/sys/block/sde` and you'll see what happened. For example, on my system `/sys/block/sda` is a link to `../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda`.

Comment: Interesting. So if I cd into a folder by symlink, then do `cd ..`, it follows the `..` without dereferencing the current folder's symlink, but if I embed the `..` into a symlink, it WILL dereference itself first. Is this behavior encoded in path_lookup() or is it a bash quirk?

Comment: Not really sure. I've gotten into the habit of changing my bash prompt to always show the real directory name so I won't get surprised when something like this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same question. The symbolic link to `/sys/block/sda/device` is relative to `/sys/devices` because `/sys/block/sda` is itself a symbolic link. Examples:

SATA drive connected to a USB -> SATA adapter

```
# ls -l /sys/block/sda
/sys/block/sda -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2.2/5-2.2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/

# readlink /sys/block/sda/device
../../../0:0:0:0

# readlink -e /sys/block/sda/device
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2.2/5-2.2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0
```

`/sys/block/sda` is a symlink to that device in `/sys/devices`, so
when you apply `../../..../` to that full path it gets you to `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2.2/5-2.2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/`, within which is the `0:0:0:0` directory referenced by the suffix of the `/sys/block/sda/device` symlink.

Side note: `/sys/devices` is derived from the UDEV path for that device, which can be obtained via `udevadm`:

```
# udevadm info --query=path /sys/block/sda
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2.2/5-2.2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda
```

Another example, this time for an NVME drive that's attached to a planar (motherboard) NVMe port:

```
# ls -l /sys/block/nv*
/sys/block/nvme0n1 -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:01:00.0/nvme/nvme0/nvme0n1/

# readlink /sys/block/nvme0n1/device
../../nvme0

# readlink -e /sys/block/nvme0n1/device
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:01:00.0/nvme/nvme0

# udevadm info --query=path /sys/block/nvme0n1
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:01:00.0/nvme/nvme0/nvme0n1
```

Comment: So this is a bug in the sysfs implementation for the /sys/block virtual directory, where it gives the response assuming you got to the node by a different directory.  Let's report this error.